# SQLite - Rolling Average/Sum

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, average, window-functions

I have a dataset as shown below, wondering how I can do a rolling average with its current record followed by next two records. Example: lets consider the first record whose total is 3 followed by 4 and 7 ,Now the rolling 3 day average for first record would be 4.6 and so on.

```
Date  Total
1      3
2      4
3      7
4      1
5      2
6      4
```

Expected output:

```
Date  Total 3day_rolling_Avg
1      3       4.6
2      4       4
3      7       3.3
4      1       2.3
5      2       null
6      4       null
```

PS: Having "null" value isn't important. This is just a sample data where I need to look at more than 3 days(Ex: 30 days rolling)

Comment: Go on. Try something

Comment: @Harish is there a reason that you accepted an answer that does not provide your expected results? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5DhWGhjDXP9rigmHVRmiU/0 and https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eLoCBPycVWBsZ3nHWPVX81/0

Comment: @forpas First approach was more accurate except handling "null" , Its much easier to implement when there are lot of records and especially when the rolling days is more than 3 days(Ex: 30 days)

Comment: *except handling "null"* but the requirement is to return nulls. So my question is why did you accept an answer that  does **not** return nulls as you asked for. Also where do you mention in the question that you may use the code for rolling averages up to 30 days?

Comment: @forpas Apologies, I should have been very clear with my question.. I'll edit my question to make it more sense

Comment: This is not the way things work here. When you change the requirement you invalidate the questions that you already have which answer the original requirement.

Comment: I apologies, I am learning to use this platform. From next time I'll make sure to come up with clear requirement to avoid this confusion. Appreciate for providing me your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the simplest approach is a window `avg()`, with the poper window frame:

```
select 
    t.*,
    avg(total) 
        over(order by date rows between current row and 2 following) as "3d_rolling_avg"
from mytable t
```

If you want to return a `null` value when there is less than 2 leading rows, as show in your expected results, then you can use `row_number()` on top of it:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when rank() over(order by date desc) <= 2
    then avg(total) 
             over(order by date rows between current row and 2 following)
    end as "3d_rolling_avg"
from mytable t
```